# Javascript canvas flickering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Seems like there are other questions like this and I'd like to avoid a buffer and/or requestAnimationFrame().

In a recent project the player is flickering but I cannot find out the reason. You can find the project on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/90wjetLa/

```
function gameEngine() {
    timer += 1;
    timer = Math.round(timer);
    // NEWSHOOT?
    player.canShoot -= 1;
    // MOVE:
    movePlayer();
    shootEngine(); // Schussbewegung & Treffer-Abfrage

    // DRAW:
    ctx.beginPath();

    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();
    drawField();
    drawPlayer();

    drawShoots();

    setTimeout(gameEngine, 1000 / 30);
}
```

Comment: There is no `const` in JavaScript.

Comment: Take a look at Mozilla-developer https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const ?

Comment: @user2531284 That is es6. Not implemented in every browser yet, also a big warning on top...

Comment: Lol what the hell. However, [don't use it](http://caniuse.com/#search=const).

Comment: So you want to avoid the 2 things specifically used to reduce flicker in animation? For heaven sake why?

Comment: `const` is sure not his problem so don't argue about it guys. Why do you want to avoid `requestAnimationFrame`? It's more convenient and also seems to improve performance. And if you're into games, you might wanna [check this out](http://www.pixijs.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you write to a visible canvas the browser want's to update the display.   Your drawing routines might be out of sync with the browsers display update.  The `requestAnimationFrame` function allows you to run all your drawing routines before the display refreshes.  Your other friend is using an invisible buffer canvas. Draw everything to the buffer canvas and then draw the buffer to the visible canvas.  The `gameEngine` function should only run once per frame and if it runs multiple times you could see flicker.  Try the following to clear multiple runs in the same frame.

(edit): You might also want to clear the canvas instead of setting width.

(edit2): You can combine the `clearRect`, `rect`, and `fill` to one command `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`.

```
var gameEngineTimeout = null;
function gameEngine() {
    // clear pending gameEngine timeout if it exists.
    clearTimeout(gameEngineTimeout);
    timer += 1;
    timer = Math.round(timer);
    // NEWSHOOT?
    player.canShoot -= 1;
    // MOVE:
    movePlayer();
    shootEngine(); // Schussbewegung & Treffer-Abfrage

    // DRAW:
    ctx.beginPath();

    //canvas.width = canvas.width;
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //ctx.fill();
    drawField();
    drawPlayer();

    drawShoots();

    gameEngineTimeout = setTimeout(gameEngine, 1000 / 30);
}
```